# Best way to delete string rows with multiple conditions in SQLite in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a database and in one of its tables i am storing paths to documents. Time from time i need to delete rows with specific extensions. I have an array with extensions and i am deleting rows from my db in this way

```
public void deletePathsExceptThis(String [] extensions){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "";
    for (int i=0; i< extensions.length-1; i++){
        query = query.concat(" LOWER(" + ALL_DOCUMENTS_PATH + ") NOT LIKE ('");
        query = query.concat(extensions[i]);
        query = query.concat("') OR ");
    }
    query = query.concat(" LOWER(" + ALL_DOCUMENTS_PATH + ") NOT LIKE ('");
    query = query.concat(extensions[extensions.length-1]) ;
    query = query.concat("')");
    db.delete(TABLE_ALL_DOCUMENTS, query, null);
}
```

But i am wondering, may be there are some more fast, productive or elegant ways to do that job? Thanks

Comment: Well, for starters, I think a `StringBuilder` is preferred over `String.concat`

Comment: There is even a [SQLiteQueryBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) - Nevermind - only suitable for SELECT ...

Comment: so StringBuilder will be faster? Because i saw some comparisons where concat took less time than using StringBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to use near the same `GLOB` word

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#glob

but this yeilds near the same result.

Or write your own regexp method.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp

but nevertheless I have to optimize your code:

```
public void deletePathsExceptThis(String [] extensions){
    if  (extensions == null || extensions.length == 0)
            return;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++){
       query.concat(" LOWER(").append(ALL_DOCUMENTS_PATH).append(") NOT LIKE ('");
       query.append(extensions[i].replaceAll("'","''"));
        String ext = i == extensions.length - 1 ? "" : " OR ";
       query.append("')").append(ext);
    }
    db.delete(TABLE_ALL_DOCUMENTS, query.toString(), null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer)

Comment: @Fedor, approve if it was helpful.  `String` are much more slower than `StringBuilders`. even `concat` method vs `append`. `Concat` creates and copies huge String class lots of times.

Comment: Thanks, i was mistaken thinking that concat is more faster. But in general my solution with creating delete request is suitable for deleting string rows with more than one condition?

Comment: @Fedor , i've not tested this. But, imho , yes.

Comment: Thanks again) Now will take in mind about StringBuilder)

Comment: lets asumme this code: `extensions[0] = "it's obviously not the best way and this is pretty valid path"`

Comment: `db.delete(TABLE_ALL_DOCUMENTS,` join `"LOWER(" + ALL_DOCUMENTS_PATH + ") NOT LIKE ?"` `extensions.length` times with `OR` , `extensions);`